# C++ convert a single binary char to int number

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators

I tried to search for answer and couldn't find a similar question.
I have an array of chars, where i need to store in the array numbers. The numbers can only be one char (not a string or more the one index in the array)

for example, 3 will turn to 11 and then to a char (mostly gibberish)

Now I want to reverse the process and from the single char c, I want to present the number in decimal form. I tried number of things, but I don’t fully understand the bitwise operations to find the number.
I would very appreciate your help!

Comment: `int i = static_cast<int>(c);`?

Comment: Can you show some sample input and expected output? Looks like the code you have just represent an integer and store them in a char

Comment: I think you are confused about values and their representations here. `int` has no "decimal form" or anything like that. It has a *value*, and that value can be *represented* using binary, decimal, hexadecimal, etc. The loop you present could be replaced with `c = <source_int>;` and you can do the same with another `int` variable.

Comment: why are you over-doing things when it already have a way ??

Comment: @ME-ON1 Isn't this obvious? Because OP is still learning and missing the relation of internal and external representation. I believe we all had this Heureka moment more or less in the past...

Comment: This is [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), please explain: why? Especially why you are doing this in such strange way. Start from begging describing what is your task,

Comment: You guys are right, I will edit the question

Comment: The number of bytes used to present an `int` is 4 (at least on my system), whereas the number of bytes used to present a `char` is 1. With an `int` you have 32 bits for the binary representation. With a `char`, you only have `8`. Therefore, you can only present numbers up to 127 with a single `char`. Bigger numbers are not possible. Maybe that is the mistake here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you mix up two different types, i.e., `int` and `char`. You cannot simply convert a binary representation of an `int` to a single `char` because they have a different number of bytes used to represent them. With a `char`, you can represent only 256 different numbers.

Below I post a code example that converts an `int` to a binary representation and from this back to an `int`.

- `decToBin(int val, int* binaryNum)` gets a value that is converted from decimal to binary. `binaryNum` is an array to store the result.
- `binToDec(int* binaryNum)` converts the binary representation to an `int` and returns it
- `clearBinNum(int* binaryNum)` clears the binary representation wiht 0
- `printBinNumber(int* binaryNum)` is a helper to print the binary representation
- `binToChar(int* binaryNum)` converts a binary representation to a `char` and returns it
- `charToDec(char charNum)` converts a `char` to a decimal representation using only bit-operations

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// This is the number of bits used to
// represent an variable of type int.
int bit_pos_count = sizeof(int) * 8;

// ---------------------------------------------------------- //
void
decToBin(int val, int* binaryNum) {
  int bit_pos = 0;
  while (val > 0) {
    if (val % 2 == 1)
      binaryNum[bit_pos] = 1;
    else
      binaryNum[bit_pos] = 0;
    val = val / 2; // integer division
    ++bit_pos;
  }
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------- //
void
clearBinNumber(int* binaryNum) {
  for (int i = 0; i < bit_pos_count; ++i)
    binaryNum[i] = 0;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------- //
void
printBinNumber(int* binaryNum) {
  for (int i = bit_pos_count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    cout << binaryNum[i];
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------- //
int
binToDec(int* binaryNum) {
  int result = 0;
  for (int i = bit_pos_count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    result = result << 1;
    if (binaryNum[i] == 1)
      result = result | 1;
  }
  return result;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------- //
char
binToChar(int* binaryNum) {
  int  char_size = sizeof(char) * 8;
  char result    = 0;
  for (int i = char_size - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    result = result << 1;
    if (binaryNum[i] == 1)
      result = result | 1;
  }
  return result;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------- //
int
charToDec(char charNum) {
  int  char_size = sizeof(char) * 8;
  char result    = 0;
  int  compare   = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < char_size; ++i) {
    if ((charNum & compare) != 0)
      result = result | compare;
    compare = compare * 2;
  }
  return result;
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------- //
int
main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
  cout << bit_pos_count << endl;
  int* binaryNum = new int[bit_pos_count];

  // printable chars start at 33
  for (int i = 33; i < 66; i += 1) {
    decToBin(i, binaryNum);
    char charNum = binToChar(binaryNum);

    cout << "decimal:             " << i << endl;
    cout << "binary:              ";
    printBinNumber(binaryNum);
    cout << endl;
    cout << "decimal from binary: " << binToDec(binaryNum) << endl;
    cout << "char from binary:    " << charNum << endl;
    cout << "decimal from char:   " << charToDec(charNum) << endl;
    cout << "---" << endl;
  }

  delete[] binaryNum;
}
```

---

```
decimal:             33
binary:              00000000000000000000000000100001
decimal from binary: 33
char from binary:    !
decimal from char:   33
---
decimal:             34
binary:              00000000000000000000000000100010
decimal from binary: 34
char from binary:    "
decimal from char:   34
---
decimal:             35
binary:              00000000000000000000000000100011
decimal from binary: 35
char from binary:    #
decimal from char:   35
---
```

Comment: @JohnFilleau: As `char` might be signed/unsigned only `0-128` is secure; before C++20, values outside this range (for conversion) would be implementation-defined...

Comment: @Jarod [C++ Fundamental Types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) says *"For every value of type unsigned char in range [0, 255], converting the value to char and then back to unsigned char produces the original value. (since C++11)"*. While the representation can be either the same as `signed` or `unsigned char`, it looks like a `char` is still able to represent the full `unsigned char` range of `[0, 255]`.

Comment: @JohnFilleau: I think you are right. I had a look at an ASCII table containing 127 entries. But a char has a size of 1 byte, i.e. 8 bits. 2^8 = 256. I edited the text accordingly.